# How to remove ViewPager from current fragment when called another fragment

Tags: android

When I called another fragment, ViewPager of first fragment is not removed. I have spent 2 days on it but didn't get it. I will be very thankful if some one will help me.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment=new SecondPage(urlToSecondPageStory,storyCategoryContainer.get(position));
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("imageurl",imageUrl);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        FragmentTransaction transaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(android.R.id.content,fragment);
    //  transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        //transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
```